# class and id css property

Tags: css

I've a div called #descr-two and a h2 and p. In css code two rules are used:

```
#descr-two h2 {color: #323232;}
#descr-two p {color: #323232;}
```

It works, but my goal is a clean and compact code, this code doesn't work:

```
#descr-two h2, p {color: #323232;}
```

Why? Where is the error? Thanks.

Comment: You Need a `#` before `descr-two` in the CSS and in the HTML you should use it like `id="descr-two"`.

Comment: Your rule will select all `p` tags you need to include the id identifier `#descr-two h2, #descr-two p`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `#descr-tw` identifier also for the `p` selector

```
#descr-two h2, #descr-two p {color: #323232;}
```

Answer (score 0):

supposing this descr-two is a name not an id
use this:

```
descr-two h2, descr-two p {color: #323232;}
```

if it is an id you should include '#':

```
#descr-two h2, #descr-two p {color: #323232;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#descr-two h2, #descr-two p {color: #323232;}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.